# Такая проблема, функция Add не вставляет значение в начало односвязного списка

Tags: c, указатели, односвязный-список

Всем привет. Такая проблема, функция Add не вставляет значение в начало односвязного списка если элементов ещё нет. Если перед её использованием использовать функцию push и добавить с помощью неё хотя бы один элемент, то работает как надо. Помогите пожалуйста

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
Node* head = NULL;
void PrintNode(const Node *head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        printf("%d ", head->value);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void Add(Node *head, int n, int val)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i<n && head)
    {
        head=head->next;
        i++;
    }
    Node *tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->value=val;
    if (!head)
    {
        head=tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        if (head->next)
        {
            tmp->next = head->next;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->next = NULL;
        }
        head->next = tmp;
    }
}
void push(Node **head, int data)
{
    Node *tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->value = data;
    tmp->next = (*head);
    (*head) = tmp;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    push(&head, 12)
    Add(head, 1, 15);
    PrintNode(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Передавайте в Add указатель на head (а сейчас вы меняете копию)

Comment: В функции `push` все правильно сделано с `head`. А в `Add` почему-то нет. Это разные люди писали? Как так получилось, что для `push` вы понимали суть проблемы, а для `Add` вдруг забыли о ней напрочь и не можете понять, в чем дело, даже наткнувшись на проблему в упор?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал как сказал "avp", передал указатель на head, не много отредактировал код функции и всё заработало. Всем спасибо)

Вот отредактированный участок кода на случай если кому-то пригодится.

```
void Add(Node **head, int n, int val)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i<n && (*head))
    {
        (*head)=(*head)->next;
        i++;
    }
    Node *tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->value=val;
    if (!(*head))
    {
        (*head)=tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        if ((*head)->next)
        {
            tmp->next = (*head)->next;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->next = NULL;
        }
        (*head)->next = tmp;
    }
}
```

Ещё в main необходимо исправить строчку на:

```
Add(&head, 1, 15);
```